# MySQL get number of distinct fields occurring more often than `x` occurs

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, a `word` table and a `document` table. The query below works to get a list of words and the number of times each word occurs in all the documents of a specific language.

```
select body, count(*) as count from word
join document on word.document_id = document.id
where document.language = 'english'
group by body
order by count(*) desc
```

It produces the desired result like this:

```
body    count
-------------
and     44
the     42
a       28
in      24
```

How can I get the number of words more common than any given word? Given the word `in`, how can I query to get `3`, since three words are more common than `in` in my documents?

Comment: One way is to join the query to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work with this, but I'd like to know if there is a better way.

```
select count(*) + 1 as rank
from (
    select body, count(*) as count
    from word
    join document on word.document_id = document.id
    where document.language = 'english'
    group by body
) t
where count > (select count
from (
    select body, count(*) as count
    from word
    join document on word.document_id = document.id
    where document.language = 'english'
    group by body
) t
where body = 'a')
```

One problem is that if you query for a word that doesn't exist, it shows `rank` = 1.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank, body, counter
FROM
(
SELECT body, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM word
JOIN document ON word.document_id = document.id
WHERE document.language = 'english'
GROUP BY body
ORDER BY counter desc
) t, (SELECT @rank := 0) r;
```

**EDIT :** IF you want to get number of words that have the count higher then ex.'in'

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank AS rank
FROM
(
SELECT body, COUNT(*) AS counter
FROM word
JOIN document ON word.document_id = document.id
WHERE document.language = 'english' and body = 'in'
GROUP BY body
ORDER BY counter desc
) t, (SELECT @rank := 0) r;
```

Comment: Unknown column 'word.document_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I think you copied something wrong, otherwise build the schema in this website http://sqlfiddle.com/ insert some data into the tables excute the query you have and share the link with me.. if it works for you please up vote my answer and mark it as accepted. thanks!

Comment: Yeah, there’s an error here; you cannot reliably group the rank like that. A good direction though.

Comment: Check the Edit now ?

Comment: This query runs and works, but I need a scalar result. Given any word, `in`, give me it's rank `4` (or number of words of higher rank, `3`, as stated in the question).